# Properties of unimodal functions

Tags: integration, analysis, probability-distributions

A probability density function $f$ is said to be unimodal if the value at which the maximum value of the function is attained is unique.

I am reading some papers on econometrics that appear to use the following result:

> For any unimodal p.d.f. $f$ that has support $\mathbb{R}$, the function $$d \mapsto \int_{k_1+d}^{k_2+d} f(x) \,dx $$ is also unimodal, where $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constants.

Any ideas of how to show this?

Answer (score 0):

You say those papers "appear" to use this result? The result is false - possibly they're not actually using it.

Consider a function $f$ so that $f(x)=1-10\,|x|$ for $|x|\le1/10$, $\,f(x)=1/2$ for $2\le x\le 2+9/5$, and $f=0$ elsewhere. (Draw a picture!)  You can easily verify that $f$ is unimodal but $d$ is not, if $k_1=0$ and $k_2=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
g(d)=\int_{d+k_1}^{d+k_2}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
Suppose the function $f$ has a unique maximum attained at $x^*$.
For $d<x^*-k_2,$ we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}g(d)}{\mathrm{d}d}=f(d+k_2)-f(d+k_1)>0,
$$
since $f(x)$ is increasing in $x$ for $x\leq x^*.$
On the other hand, for $d>x^*-k_1$, we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}g(d)}{\mathrm{d}d}=f(d+k_2)-f(d+k_1)<0,
$$
since $f(x)$ is decreasing in $x$ for $x\geq x^*.$

For $x^*-k_2<d<x^*-k_1$, assuming that $f$ is differentiable, then
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2g(d)}{\mathrm{d}d^2}=f'(d+k_2)-f'(d+k_1)<0.
$$

Combining the three cases together, we have $g(d)$ has a unique maximum at $ d^* \in [x^*-k_2, x^*-k_1].$